# Get-Childitem -Filter until third character

Tags: powershell

Can someone please help me filter through some folders and choose only those i want, i have a folder "Global" and within it there are subfolders named as follow:

```
0000db12
0001db12
000kbv_09
000kh-rba
001C7o-p4
001C7p-0ol
```

i would like to have only the folders that start with either '000' or '001', store them in variables and ignore the rest, currently i am using these two simple lines:

```
$000Folders = Get-ChildItem $path -filter '000*'
$001Folders = Get-ChildItem $path -filter '001*'
```

with '001' it's working well even though i knwo it's not so efficient but with '000' i am getting some unwanted folders like '0000db12 and 0001db12', any help to improve the filtering would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add switch `-File` to the cmdlet of you don't want directories

Comment: @Theo thanks for the hint, i do want directories though :)

Comment: That wasn't clear because of _I would like to have only the **files**_..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using a hash table to store the filtered items with the keys being the first three characters of the target file/folder. You can add additional `Where-Object` commands or filter at the `-Path` parameter to limit your result set further.

**Using Group-Object (less efficient but more concise):**

```
$hash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '00*' |
    Group-Object {$_.BaseName.SubString(0,3)} | Foreach-Object {
        $hash[$_.Name] = $_.Group
    }
$hash # outputs the hash table
$hash['000'] # outputs files and folders that start with 000
```

**Using if-statements (more efficient):**

```
$hash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '00*' | Foreach-Object {
    $FirstThree = $_.BaseName.SubString(0,3)
    if (!$hash[$FirstThree]) {
        $hash[$FirstThree] = [Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]@($_)
    } else {
        $hash[$FirstThree].Add($_)
    }
}
$hash # outputs the hash table
$hash['000'] # outputs files and folders that start with 000
```

---

If your object names have less than 3 characters, then `$_.BaseName.Substring(0,3)` will throw an error. You can use other techniques that will never error but capture the entire name if less than 3 characters. You can also just use `Where {$_.BaseName.Length -gt 2}` to ignore names with less than 3 characters.

AFAIK `-Filter` only supports simple wildcarding (`*` and `?`). If you want to involve character sets in your wildcarding, you can do those at the `-Path` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path\00[1-3]*" # objects the begin with 001,002,003
```

Comment: thank you for explaining, the output of ´$hash['000']´ in the two approaches above still contains unwanted folders like **0000delete** and **0001delete**, so it does return only the folders that begin with '000' but it also includes the ones that have '0000' or '0001' at the beginning of the name, so it doesn't take only the first three charachters consideration,is there a way around that?

Comment: what characters do you expect to come after `000` in the names of your results?

Comment: my bad :), your question just helped me realize the confusion i was having, it could be literally any character after '000' which means having a folder in the output such as **0001delete** for example shouldn't be a problem as long as it started with '000', thank you again for the help

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard filters support characters sets with ranges, so you could do

```
$000Folders = Get-ChildItem $path -filter '000[1-9a-z]*'
```

Here, the first three characters must be `000`, but the fourth has to be a non-0 alphanumeric, followed by anything

Comment: thank you for replying, i have tried that but unfortunately it is not giving back any output!

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at it.  This excludes files or folders with 'db12' in the name.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -filter 000* | where name -notmatch db12
```